# How to read back the "random-seed" from a saved model of Dynet

Tags: python, lstm, dynet

I have a model already trained by **dynet** library. But i forget the **--dynet-seed** parameter when training this model. 
Does anyone know how to read back this parameter from the saved model?
Thank you in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't read back the seed parameter. Dynet model does not save the seed parameter. The obvious reason is, it is not required at testing time. Seed is only used to set fixed initial weights, random shuffling etc. for different experimental runs. At testing time no parameter initialisation or shuffling is required. So, no need to save seed parameter.

To the best of my knowledge, none of the other libraries like tensorflow, pytorch etc. save the seed parameter as well.